# include in eclipse for layouts throwing "no resource found"

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

I am absolutely new to Java and Eclipse. I have two layout-files under /res/layout:

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <include layout="@layout/layoutTst" />
</LinearLayout>
```

layout_test.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layoutTst"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

When I try to compile at the "include" - part I get this message:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type error: Error: No resource
found that matches the given name (at 'layout' with value
'@layout/layoutTst').   activity_main.xml   /YouSherlock/res/layout line
6   Android AAPT Problem
```

So what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the layout filename (**layout_test**.xml), not the ID of the root in that layout.

```
<include layout="@layout/layout_test" />
```

Comment: I knew it was a noob question. Thanks :)

Comment: @OleAlbers No problem, it happens! Glad you have it working now! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 @layout/layoutTst
```

should be the name of the file not its android:id

```
 @layout/layout_test
```